Should I use single-root I/O virtualization?
Setting up a Hyper-V Host in Windows Server 2022 Datacenter for the first time (I've previously only done 2019 and older on Standard or Enterprise), and there's a single-root I/O virtualization option I haven't seen before for the vSwitch:

I've read a few things on this option, but I can't find any guidance. Everything just says it's used to improve virtualization performance by bypassing the software vswitch and using the PCIe bus directly. That sounds like a no-brainer.
And yet... the option is not checked by default. I expect there is a reason for this.
Should I use this option? What considerations are there for using or not using it?

SR-IOV is a form of IO-virtualization which leverages the NIC hardware-based virtualization support.
Basically, the integrated chip provides a set of multiple abstracted NICs (each with its relative registers and memory-mapped areas) avoiding the overhead of a software-based network virtualization.
Should you use it? SR-IOV generally gives better performance but it only provides a finite (and often low, ie: 4/8/16) number of abstracted interfaces. Moreover, being an hardware-based solution, it is less flexible than a software based approach.

So as long as I fit within the limitations, it's a solid win and safe?

It entirely depends on the specific hardware implementation. Intel NICs have a good reputation, but I don't have first hand experience to share - I tend to use KVM paravirtualized network driver rather than SRV-IO.
